# MyPy doesn't allow constrained TypeVar's to be covariant? Defining a generic dict with constrained but covariant key-val types

Tags: python-3.x, generics, covariance, mypy

I'm trying to define a custom generic dict, whose keys are of type `T_key` and values are of type `T_val`.
I also want to put constraints on `T_key` and `T_val`, such that `T_key` can only be of type `A` or `B` or their subclass.

How do I accomplish this?

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

class A: ...
class B: ...

class Asub(A): ...
class Bsub(B): ...

T_key = TypeVar('T_key', A, B, covariant=True)
T_val = TypeVar('T_val', A, B, covariant=True)


class MyDict(Generic[T_key, T_val]): ...


w: MyDict[   A,    B]
x: MyDict[   A, Bsub]
y: MyDict[Asub,    B]
z: MyDict[Asub, Bsub]
```

When I try to check this, mypy gives errors on annotations of `x`, `y` and `z`. Only the annotation for `w` works as expected.

```
generic.py:17: error: Value of type variable "T_val" of "MyDict" cannot be "Bsub"
generic.py:18: error: Value of type variable "T_key" of "MyDict" cannot be "Asub"
generic.py:19: error: Value of type variable "T_key" of "MyDict" cannot be "Asub"
generic.py:19: error: Value of type variable "T_val" of "MyDict" cannot be "Bsub"
```

I don't understand why `Asub` is not a valid type for `T_key` even with `covariant=True` specified.

What am I missing here?

> mypy version: 0.630

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not what covariance means. With a covariant type variable `T` and a generic class `Foo[T]`, instances of `Foo[Subclass]` are also considered instances of `Foo[Superclass]`. Covariance has no effect on what types may be substituted for `T`.

If your `B` were defined as

```
class B(A): ...
```

instead of

```
class B: ...
```

, then a value of type `MyDict[B, B]` would be considered a valid value of type `MyDict[A, A]` by static type checkers due to covariance. You would still not be able to create a value of type `MyDict[ASub, BSub]`, because the only valid values of your type variables are `A` and `B`.

The concept you're looking for is *bounded* type variables, using the `bound` keyword argument, not constrained type variables. It looks like you can specify a union as the bound, which comes as quite a surprise to me, so declaring the type variables as

```
T_key = TypeVar('T_key', bound=Union[A, B])
T_val = TypeVar('T_val', bound=Union[A, B])
```

should work.

Comment: I'm confused. If I still can't make `MyDict[C, C]`, then what allows me to make `MyDict[B, B]`? Do you mean that with covariance I can't create `MyDict[B, B]` either, but if I could then it would be considered a subclass of `MyDict[A, A]`? Anyway, is there a way I could accomplish the desired behavior? Thanks :)

Comment: @PragyAgarwal: You can make `MyDict[B, B]` because `B` is one of the options you specified when you created `T_key` and `T_val`. As for doing what you're looking for, the concept you're looking for is bounded type variables, but I don't think Python supports the kind of bound you want.

Comment: That makes sense. So if `bound=` allowed me to provide more than one class (which it currently doesn't), I could have accomplished this? Is there any other workaround that you could suggest? Thanks :)

Comment: @PragyAgarwal: Maybe see if it makes sense to introduce a common superclass for `A` and `B`? Or see if specifying a union as the bound does anything useful? (I would be surprised if the union works; I don't think mypy's concept of subclassing works like that.)

Comment: Can't extract a superclass unfortunately, since it will be object. Yeah, Union works :D Just discovered it via https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2702 I had not tried it since TypeVar needs concrete types for the constraint parameters.

Comment: @PragyAgarwal: Huh, it does work. My experiments also show a union-bounded type variable accepting types listed in the union or any of their subclasses, and rejecting non-subclasses.

Comment: @user2357112 Can you clarify in your second paragraph, including what types you are talking about? I am assuming it is ``TypeVar('T_key', A, B, covariant=True)`` and ``A`` and ``B(A)``, but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

## solution:

Turns out bound can accept Unions.

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Union

class A: ...
class B: ...

class Asub(A): ...
class Bsub(B): ...



T_key = TypeVar('T_key', bound=Union[A, B])
T_val = TypeVar('T_val', bound=Union[A, B])


class MyDict(Generic[T_key, T_val]): ...


w: MyDict[   A,    B]  # passes
x: MyDict[   A, Bsub]  # passes
y: MyDict[Asub,    B]  # passes
z: MyDict[Asub, Bsub]  # passes
bad: MyDict[int, int]  # Type argument "builtins.int" of "MyDict" must be a subtype of "Union[generic.A, generic.B]"
```