# Python typing what does TypeVar(A, B, covariant=True) mean?

Tags: python, oop, covariance, mypy, static-typing

Today I took a deep dive into Liskov's Substitution Principle and covariance/contravariance.

And I got stuck on the difference between:

1. `T = TypeVar("T", bound=Union[A, B])`
2. `T = TypeVar("T", A, B, covariant=True)`

---

**My Understanding of #1**

[Difference between TypeVar('T', A, B) and TypeVar('T', bound=Union[A, B])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59933946/difference-between-typevart-a-b-and-typevart-bound-uniona-b)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59937840/11163122) clearly states `T` can be :

> 1. `Union[A, B]` (or a union of any subtypes of `A` and `B` such as `Union[A, BChild]`)
> 2. `A` (or any subtype of `A`)
> 3. `B` (or any subtype of `B`)

This makes perfect sense to me.

---

**My *Flawed* Understanding of #2**

[MyPy doesn't allow constrained TypeVar's to be covariant? Defining a generic dict with constrained but covariant key-val types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52997754/mypy-doesnt-allow-constrained-typevars-to-be-covariant-defining-a-generic-dic)

Re-mentions the `bound=Union[A, B]` case, but does not get at the meaning of option #2, `A, B, covariant=True`.

I have tried playing around with `mypy`, and can't seem to figure it out. 
 **Can anyone point out what this means?**

I *think* it means:

1. `A` (or any subtype of `A`)
2. `B` (or any subtype of `B`)

(aka it excludes the `Union` case from above)

---

****Edit****

It was asked in the comments:

> Are you sure that they're actually different?

Here's sample code to show the difference.  The errors come from `mypy==0.770`.

```py
from typing import Union, TypeVar, Generic


class A: pass

class ASub(A): pass

class B: pass


# Case 1... Success: no issues found
# T = TypeVar("T", bound=Union[A, B])

# Case 2... error: Value of type variable "T" of "SomeGeneric" cannot be "ASub"
T = TypeVar("T", A, B, covariant=True)


class SomeGeneric(Generic[T]): pass

class SomeGenericASub(SomeGeneric[ASub]): pass
```

---

****Edit 2****

I ended up asking about this in [python/mypy #8806: Generic[T_co] erroring when T_co = TypeVar("T_co", A, B, covariant=True) and passed subclass of A](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8806)

This cleared up some misunderstandings I had.  Turns out `TypeVar("T", A, B, covariant=True)` isn't really correct, knowing the value restrictions `A` and `B` aren't actually covariant.

Use of `covariant=True` syntax is only helpful when they're related.

Comment: Are you sure that they're actually different?  Unions are themselves covariant so it's not obvious to me that there's any difference between these two expressions.

Comment: Yes @Samwise I just edited my question to add sample code demonstrating the difference

Comment: I think mypy's handling of type variables with explicit options is currently buggy. With `T = TypeVar("T", A, B)`, even without covariance, it allows things like `x = SomeGeneric[ASub]()`, but not `x: SomeGeneric[ASub]`. It shouldn't allow the creation of values of type `SomeGeneric[ASub]` at all.

Comment: Okay, so maybe `mypy` is buggy.  Can anyone at least explain to me what `T = TypeVar("T", A, B, covariant=True)` actually means?  Are you saying that it should be identical to the `bound=Union[A, B]` case, and if yes, why?

Comment: It *should* mean a type variable that can only be `A` or `B`, which happens to be covariant. It is not supposed to be identical to the union-bounded case.

Comment: For example, with `T = TypeVar("T", A, ASub, covariant=True)`, it would be okay to do `x: SomeGeneric[A] = SomeGeneric[ASub]()`, which would be invalid with `T = TypeVar("T", bound=Union[A, ASub])`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica to me, `A, ASub, covariant=True` is sort of redundant to just saying `bound=A`.  Would you agree?  I think it makes more sense in the `A, B` case, which I sadly still don't understand :(

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer: `T = TypeVar("T", A, ASub, covariant=True)` would reject `SomeOtherASubclass`.

Comment: (Don't assume that any of this is useful just based on whether it's allowed. You can do all sorts of things that aren't very useful.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, I agree that `A, ASub, covariant=True` should reject `SomeOtherASub` because `SomeOtherASub` isn't a subclass of `ASub`.  What about `T = TypeVar("T", A, B, covariant=True)`, and then testing with just plain ol' `ASub`?  Do you think that it errors is a bug in `mypy`?  I am still uncertain of the general recipe of `A, B, covariant=True`

Answer (score 93):

Covariance and contra-variance are terms that relate to the intersection between object orientation and generics.

Here's the question this concept is trying to answer:

1. We have a couple of "regular", "object-oriented" classes, `Base` and `Derived`.
2. We also have some generic type - let's say `List[T]`.
3. We know that `Derived` can be used anywhere `Base` can - does that mean that `List[Derived]` can be used wherever `List[Base]` can?
4. Could it be the other way around? Maybe it's the reverse direction and now `List[Base]` can be used wherever `List[Derived]` can?

If the answer to (3) is yes, it's called ***covariance*** and we'll say declare `List` as having `covariance=True`. If the answer to (4) is true, it's called ***contra-variance***. If none is true, it's ***invariant***.

Bounds also come from the intersection of OO and generics. When we define a generic type `MyType<T>` - does it mean that `T` can be any type at all? Or, may I impose some limitations on what `T` might be? Bounds allow me to state that the upper bound of `T` is, for example, the class `Derived`. In that case, `Base` can't be used with `MyType` - but `Derived` and all its subclasses can.

The definition of covariance and contravariance can be found in [this section of PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance).

Comment: A nice shorthand: is the generic type used only as a method argument type for your class? If so, probably contravariant. Is it used only as a method return type for your class? If so, probably covariant. Is it used as an attribute type for your class, and those attributes are *immutable*? If so, probably covariant. In all other cases, probably invariant.