# Why does mypy consider `Mapping` with more restrictions on keys/values not compatible with the one with fewer restrictions

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

The code below results in a mypy error

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping

def f(a: Mapping[str | bytes, str | bytes | int | float]):
    print(a)


x: Mapping[str, int] = {'a': 1}
f(x)
```

```
file.py:8: error: Argument 1 to "f" has incompatible type "Mapping[str, int]"; expected
"Mapping[str | bytes, str | bytes | int | float]"  [arg-type]
    f(x)
      ^
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

The possible fix is this one:

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping

def f(a: Mapping[str | bytes, str | bytes | int | float]):
    print(a)


x: Mapping[str | bytes, int] = {'a': 1}
f(x)
```

Although, I understand how to fix it, I don't understand what's the reason that `Mapping[str, int]` is incompatible with `Mapping[str | bytes, str | bytes | int | float]`?

Mypy version:

```
mypy 1.4.1 (compiled: no)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mapping` is not [covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61568462/5986907) in its key type. You can see this either by looking at the definition, for which I can only find the [docs for the deprecated `typing.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Mapping), or by looking at where the key appears in the methods on `Mapping`. Since it appears as an argument, it can be either contravariant or invariant but not covariant (it's a little more complex than that but it's a good rule of thumb).

Comment: Yes, thank you for the explanation. According to [this comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/typing.py#L2715) in cpython's source it's covariant only for the value type, not for the key type.